# Oracle SQL Where Case Error

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this query that I'm trying to run, the problem is that I keep getting "Missing Keyword" notifactions. I'm trying to generate a query that will calculate the system date against an algebrically calcualted value, if they are equal then the Where statement will search based on the values after the "THEN" portion of my case. Can someone help with these?

```
WHERE
     CASE 

                WHEN (SYSDATE) = (42192+30*(TRUNC((((SYSDATE)*52)/365)/4) - (((42192*52)/365)/4)))  THEN 'THE.DESCRIPTION = 'TEST-01''
                WHEN (SYSDATE) = (42193+30*(TRUNC((((SYSDATE)*52)/365)/4) - (((42193*52)/365)/4)))  THEN 'THE.DESCRIPTION = 'TEST-02''
                WHEN (SYSDATE) = (42194+30*(TRUNC((((SYSDATE)*52)/365)/4) - (((42194*52)/365)/4)))  THEN 'THE.DESCRIPTION = 'TEST-03''
                WHEN (SYSDATE) = (42195+30*(TRUNC((((SYSDATE)*52)/365)/4) - (((42195*52)/365)/4)))  THEN 'THE.DESCRIPTION = 'TEST-04''
                WHEN (SYSDATE) = (42198+30*(TRUNC((((SYSDATE)*52)/365)/4) - (((42198*52)/365)/4)))  THEN 'THE.DESCRIPTION = 'TEST-05''
                WHEN (SYSDATE) = (42199+30*(TRUNC((((SYSDATE)*52)/365)/4) - (((42199*52)/365)/4)))  THEN 'THE.DESCRIPTION = 'TEST-06''
                WHEN (SYSDATE) = (42200+30*(TRUNC((((SYSDATE)*52)/365)/4) - (((42200*52)/365)/4)))  THEN 'THE.DESCRIPTION = 'TEST-07''
                WHEN (SYSDATE) = (42201+30*(TRUNC((((SYSDATE)*52)/365)/4) - (((42201*52)/365)/4)))  THEN 'THE.DESCRIPTION = 'TEST-08''
                WHEN (SYSDATE) = (42202+30*(TRUNC((((SYSDATE)*52)/365)/4) - (((42202*52)/365)/4)))  THEN 'THE.DESCRIPTION = 'TEST-09''
                WHEN (SYSDATE) = (42205+30*(TRUNC((((SYSDATE)*52)/365)/4) - (((42205*52)/365)/4)))  THEN 'THE.DESCRIPTION = 'TEST-10''
                WHEN (SYSDATE) = (42206+30*(TRUNC((((SYSDATE)*52)/365)/4) - (((42206*52)/365)/4)))  THEN 'THE.DESCRIPTION = 'TEST-11''
                WHEN (SYSDATE) = (42207+30*(TRUNC((((SYSDATE)*52)/365)/4) - (((42207*52)/365)/4)))  THEN' THE.DESCRIPTION = 'TEST-12''
                WHEN (SYSDATE) = (42208+30*(TRUNC((((SYSDATE)*52)/365)/4) - (((42208*52)/365)/4)))  THEN 'THE.DESCRIPTION = 'TEST-13''
                WHEN (SYSDATE) = (42209+30*(TRUNC((((SYSDATE)*52)/365)/4) - (((42209*52)/365)/4)))  THEN 'THE.DESCRIPTION = 'TEST-14''
                WHEN (SYSDATE) = (42212+30*(TRUNC((((SYSDATE)*52)/365)/4) - (((42212*52)/365)/4)))  THEN 'THE.DESCRIPTION = 'TEST-15''
                WHEN (SYSDATE) = (42213+30*(TRUNC((((SYSDATE)*52)/365)/4) - (((42213*52)/365)/4)))  THEN 'THE.DESCRIPTION = 'TEST-16''
                WHEN (SYSDATE) = (42214+30*(TRUNC((((SYSDATE)*52)/365)/4) - (((42214*52)/365)/4)))  THEN 'THE.DESCRIPTION = 'TEST-17''
                WHEN (SYSDATE) = (42215+30*(TRUNC((((SYSDATE)*52)/365)/4) - (((42215*52)/365)/4)))  THEN 'THE.DESCRIPTION = 'TEST-18''
                WHEN (SYSDATE) = (42216+30*(TRUNC((((SYSDATE)*52)/365)/4) - (((42216*52)/365)/4)))  THEN 'THE.DESCRIPTION = 'TEST-19''
                WHEN (SYSDATE) = (42219+30*(TRUNC((((SYSDATE)*52)/365)/4) - (((42219*52)/365)/4)))  THEN 'THE.DESCRIPTION = 'TEST-20''
                WHEN (SYSDATE) = (42220+30*(TRUNC((((SYSDATE)*52)/365)/4) - (((42220*52)/365)/4)))  THEN 'THE.DESCRIPTION = 'TEST-21''

                END
```

);

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do the sub-query to select the value that you are looking for in case-when-then and then do the WHERE statement in main query. Example:

```
SELECT * FROM suppliers WHERE office_name = (
SELECT 
CASE
  WHEN supplier_name = 'IBM' and supplier_type = 'Hardware' THEN 'North office'
  WHEN supplier_name = 'IBM' and supplier_type = 'Software' THEN 'South office'
END
FROM suppliers;
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to compare the overall case expression result to something, you can't do a comparison within each `then`. You also have your quotes messed up which isn't helping understand what you're doing. But it looks like you want something more like:

```
WHERE
  THE.DESCRIPTION = CASE 
    WHEN (SYSDATE) = (42192+30*(TRUNC((((SYSDATE)*52)/365)/4) - (((42192*52)/365)/4)))  THEN 'TEST-01'
    WHEN (SYSDATE) = (42193+30*(TRUNC((((SYSDATE)*52)/365)/4) - (((42193*52)/365)/4)))  THEN 'TEST-02'
    ...
  END
```

Though I'd reverse the `when` calculation so you end up checking something much simpler; since `sysdate*52` [isn't going to work](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7db59d16c/2194) I'm really not sure how to untangle that part.